# How to list all methods of data types or built-in/user-defined functions in julia?

Tags: julia

I'm switching from a python background. In python there is a built-in named `dir` which can be called upon anything to list out every method one can perform on it.

Is there a similar way in **julia** to list all the methods that one can perform on a certain datatype just like python?

Answer (score 4):

Use `methodswith`:

```
help?> methodswith
search: methodswith

  methodswith(typ[, module or function]; supertypes::Bool=false])

  Return an array of methods with an argument of type typ.

  The optional second argument restricts the search to a particular module or function (the default is all top-level modules).

  If keyword supertypes is true, also return arguments with a parent type of typ, excluding type Any.
```

Sample usage:

```
julia> methodswith(String, Base)
[1] ==(a::String, b::String) in Base at strings/string.jl:106
[2] abspath(a::String) in Base.Filesystem at path.jl:383
[3] ascii(s::String) in Base at strings/util.jl:612
[4] chomp(s::String) in Base at strings/util.jl:125
[5] cmp(a::String, b::String) in Base at strings/string.jl:100
[6] codeunit(s::String) in Base at strings/string.jl:86
[7] codeunit(s::String, i::Integer) in Base at strings/string.jl:89
[8] dump(io::IOContext, x::String, n::Int64, indent) in Base at show.jl:1942
...
```

Note thay in Julia very often several methods are defined for abstract supertypes so often it is worth to use the `supertypes` parameter as in:

```
methodswith(Dict, Base, supertypes=true)
```

Comment: I am unable to find the methods applicable on Dictionaries or arrays or tuples by `methodswith`. I want it to list methods like keys(), values(). pop(), push() etc. which work for Dictionaries. Is it possible by some means?

Comment: There is one more thing you would wanna add into the answer, how to list it for externally installed Packages. Thanks:)

Comment: replace `Base` with the package name such as `methodswith(DataFrame, DataFrames)`